# ROS+Kinect+ARM device+Openni

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, kinect, openni, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get Openni drivers from outside of ROS working on a BeagleBoard and got the Kinect to at least work on the board.But, I my goal is get to a point where I can run "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" from the BeagleBoard and it will start publishing the data from the Kinect.
The problem is that everytime I try to install openni_camera or openni_launch I end up with dependency issues for the ARM board. Does someone have any hints on how to get openni_camera or openni_launch on a BeagleBoard or Gumstix or and ARM board?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I also already know how to install a basic version of ROS on the BeagleBoard (with openni_launch/camera or pcl).

Edit 2: I have mostly tries with groovy and Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 but I'm open to any distribution and any OS as long as it works.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67459/ros+kinect+arm-device+openni/) by [Qandeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5107/qandeel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. You're on your own.

Most of the previous questions and answers on this topic are along the lines of "it doesn't quite work" and/or "I can't get it to compile"

Asking the same question multiple times will not yield better results.

If you post a question with a specific compile error or a dependency problem that you're having, along with the specific versions of Ubuntu and ROS that you're using, you may get more positive results.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qandeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5107/qandeel/) on 2013-07-16**:
According to this(http://kinect-with-ros.976505.n3.nabble.com/Ros-kinect-kinect-on-ARM-td2654041.html) thread, it seems like some people have managed to get it to work with different ARM devices. I am not sure on what changes they made to make it work.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-16**:
From my quick reading, the summary on that thread is that they were able to get the driver to run, but it did not run reliably and they were not able to get any useful data out of it.

That thread is also 2+ years old, and was probably using now-obsolete versions of ROS and Ubuntu.